# How to get CVSS score from CWE/WASC/Source ID in ZAP

Tags: owasp, zap

In OWASP ZAP report, there are following 3 fields.

1. CWE ID
2. WASC ID
3. Source ID

Is there a way to get CVSS score using any of above fields? If yes then could someone please explain.

Answer (score 1):

There isn't a way. Calculating CVSS would require specific details of the individual issues and targets, not all of which would be known to ZAP.

There's an online calculator here that you could plug details into: https://nvd.nist.gov/vuln-metrics/cvss/v3-calculator